# Sonar rule for interfaces only RSPEC-1213

Tags: java, sonarqube, rules

I want to modify / make the rule target only public interfaces (not public classes etc). Is this possible ? Im using this rule in Java code but its too strict for my project and I would love to know if there is a way to change it a little bit.

Link for rule: https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-1213

Answer (score 1):

For an existing ruleset on SonarQube, talk to your sonar administrator to change the rules that are enforced on the code and remove that particular one from global enforcement.

There have been a few times I've gone to the admins of the tool for the install that I use and said "this rule isn't one that I care about or will enforce and only makes it confusing" and had them remove that rule from the globally run ruleset.

---

Is it possible to write your own rule?

Yes, it is possible. From SonarQube's docs: [Adding coding rules](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/extension-guide/adding-coding-rules/) you have some options.  Either you can write a plugin for SonarQube and add that to your instance ([docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/extension-guide/developing-a-plugin/plugin-basics/)), or you can write an external application that analyzes the code which SonarQube consumes.

If you don't have your own instance of sonarqube or aren't up to writing the associated plugin or external tooling... you might want to instead lookout PMD ([site](https://pmd.github.io/#home)).

For PMD, writing a custom rule can be much simpler ([docs](https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_userdocs_extending_writing_pmd_rules.html)).  One of the ways that PMD works is by 'compiling' the Java code into an XML representation of the abstract syntax tree for Java and then running xpath queries against that XML ([tutorial](https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_userdocs_extending_your_first_rule.html)).

The xpath rule can then be included in a project's configuration.

---

What about turning it off for the code that I'm working on?

If a specific rule is one that you don't want to invoke, you could suppress it with `@SuppressWarnings("java:S106")` (that particular spares warnings is for System.out.println use, but the same structure can be used for other warnings) or by adding `// NOSONAR too strict` on the line.  There are spots where I have such comments where following the rule for a particular set of code is problematic and suppress it for that line, method, or class - with the comment about *why* that is done.

---

That particular rule... I'm gonna agree with the Java (and now Oracle) guidelines and follow it.  The reason is that if anyone else works on the code, they'll expect it to follow that convention.  Having a consistent understanding of what things should be where in code so that another developer doesn't need to go dig through an entire file to find the constructor when it is expected to be at the top (under the field definition) is a good thing.  What's more, it limits the future cases where a developer goes through to make things consistent with conventions and results in a lot of `style: updating code to follow style guide` commits later.